# Field value populated ether by another field value or by user input based on a Boolean field in QGIS form

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qfield, trigger

I'm creating a winter bird survey form in QGIS for use in Qfield.

There is a field called "mixed" which records whether a flock is mixed(1) or not(0).
Another field called "sp_count" for the count of the dominant species and a final field called "fl_count" which records the total flock size. All fields are integers.

My aim is that when "mixed" = '0' then "fl_count" = "sp_count" but when "mixed" = '1' then "fl_count" = the user input.

To this end, I currently have my default value set as `case when "mixed" = '0' then "sp_count" end` but this defaults "fl_count" as NULL when "mixed" = '1'. Is there a way to achieve my aim?

I'm currently doing this in the attributes form designer but if not possible here, could it be controlled by a trigger?

Comment: Is that not correct behaviour? If mixed=1, then user overwrites default null value of fl_count !

Comment: No, it also overwrites user input on update.

Comment: In which case, untick 'apply default value on update'

Comment: @Oisin when unticking that, then when digitising a new feature, `fl_count` doesn't seem to get the `sp_count` value when `mixed` is `0`. As the QGIS widgets warning says, 'Using fields in a default expression only works if "Apply default value on update" is checked'. You need to enable that and complete the `CASE` expression - `CASE WHEN "mixed" = 0 THEN "sp_count"  ELSE "fl_count" END` so it will return the value of `fl_count` (either existing, or modified if so), rather than resetting to `NULL` every time there is an update.

Comment: The side effect of that approach is that if you change `mixed` from `0` to `1`,  `fl_count` will retain the same value it had earlier, i.e. the `sp_count` value. But you may want an additional rule that if `mixed` = `1` then `fl_count` must be greater than `sp_count`. You can add a constraint to `fl_count` with this expression: `CASE WHEN "mixed" = 1 THEN "fl_count" > "sp_count" ELSE "fl_count" = "sp_count" END`

Comment: @she_weeds. Despite the warning  'Using fields in a default expression only works if "Apply default value on update" is checked', similar expressions work for me without 'Apply default value on update'. You could also add to the CASE statement when fl_count > sp_count the fl_count, to leave existing values for that condition.

Comment: @she_weeds Thanks so much this now works better than hoped.